# Retrieve sharepoint file sharelink with Office365-REST-Python-Client

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint, runtime-error, office365

I've got this issue with the Office365-REST-Python-Client library
I am trying to extract the sharelink of a file that is in my sharepoint:
I wrote my code based on this thread :(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1158967/try-to-get-sharedlink-sharepoint-in-python)

So here is what I tried:

```py
#file url
ctx = ClientContext(url_shrpt, ctx_auth)

#file folder => name of the folder in sharepoint
#file name => name of the file I want the share link

target_file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_url('/sites/Test_sharepoint12/' + file_folder + file_name)
result = target_file.share_link(SharingLinkKind.AnonymousView).execute_query()
print(json.dumps(result.value.to_json(), indent=4))
link_url = result.value.sharingLinkInfo.Url

print(link_url)
```

I get this error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

office365.runtime.client_request_exception.ClientRequestException: ('-1, System.InvalidOperationException', 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.', "400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Test_sharepoint12/_api/Web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('%2Fsites%2FTest_sharepoint12%2FShared%20Documents%2FBase_documentaire%2Fcross%20comparison.xlsx')/listItemAllFields/ShareLink")
```

Can someone help me sort this out?
Or suggest a different way of doing what I tryna do

Thanks y'all :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do it within your company sharepoint.

You may try to change from `SharingLinkKind.AnonymousView` to `SharingLinkKind.OrganizationView`

I had the same issue and I did the change, and it worked.